# JSON POST to PHP works locally, not on Plesk server

Tags: php, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an app using Ionic (AngularJS) and have encountered a frustrating problem. I have a small form that needs to be submitted to an API that writes these values to my database.

The code in my controller is this:

```
.controller('RequestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.update = function(request) {
    var link = 'http://www.linktomyphpscript.com/script.php';
    alert(request.name);
    $http.post(link, {name: request.name}).then(function (res){
      alert(res.data);
    })
  }
})
```

I created a small PHP file to test the POST:

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $name = $request->name;

    if ($name != "") {
        echo $name;
    }
    else {
        echo "Error finding name";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Not called properly with name parameter!";
}
?>
```

If I run this code using Mamp on my local machine, everything works. I get the value I sent to the localhost in return.

However, if I upload my PHP to my server and do the exact same thing, I receive the "Error finding name" error.

I have tried to use `json_decode($_POST['name'])` but that doesn't work, not even on localhost.

using `var_dump($_POST)` return an empty array.

The only difference in PHP is that locally I'm running 5.6.10 and on the server it's 5.4.32. 
On the server, always_populate_raw_post_data is set to False, while locally it's set to 0.
When I start my PHP code with `ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data', '0');` the problem stays the same.

Are there other variables that I need to check in php.ini or is there something wrong with the way I post my data?